# I can't get my JLabels to show. I'm not sure if I placed them in the wrong position in the BorderLayout. Help! My code is below

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the main class where JLabels and lists are initialized:

```
public dutchessHousing() {
    super("Plan options");
    contents = getContentPane();
    contents.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    selections = new JLabel (suiteList[0]); 
    suitesScrollPane = new JScrollPane(suites);
    meals = new JList<String>(mealList);
    housingOptions = new JLabel();
    mealOptions = new JLabel();
    total = new JLabel();


    contents.add(suitesScrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
    contents.add(selections, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contents.add(meals, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    contents.add(total, BorderLayout.WEST);

    setSize(750, 700);
    addComponent();
    showCalculations();
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Method to show calculations in frame. housingOptions is supposed to show on the top of the frame, before the JList.

```
public static void showCalculations() {
        housingOptions = new JLabel("Choose one of the following housing options: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        mealOptions = new JLabel("Choose one of the following meal plan options: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        total = new JLabel();
        housingOptions.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contents.add(housingOptions);
        contents.add(mealOptions);
        contents.add(total);



        }
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dutchessHousing frame = new dutchessHousing();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(selections);
    frame.add(suitesScrollPane);
    frame.add(meals);
    //frame.add(housingOptions);
    frame.add(mealOptions);
    frame.add(total);

    showCalculations();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contents.add(suitesScrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
contents.add(selections, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contents.add(meals, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
contents.add(total, BorderLayout.WEST);
setSize(750, 700);
addComponent();
showCalculations();
```

Above you add components to different areas of the BorderLayout which is reasonable.

But then when you invoke the showCalculations() method you use:

```
    contents.add(housingOptions);
    contents.add(mealOptions);
    contents.add(total);
```

Which will replace all the components added in the "CENTER" with the "total" component since only the last component added to any region of the BorderLayout will be visible.

So you first need to add all the labels to a panel. Then add the panel to the "BorderLayout.CENTER"

Comment: Thank you for your response! Should I do this in the dutchessHousing method or the showCalculations method?

Comment: @zachdorcinville you do it where you think it is appropriate. I was just point out that you are using the layout manager incorrectly. How you want to resolve the issue is up to you.